# How to create a new skin for Horloger software

Tags: skin

If you used [Horloger](http://amine5a5.deviantart.com/art/Horloger-V1-0-Final-206066131) you know that is a clock app with a handsome of skins. Its skins are made up from an .ini file and some images. Its default skin is similar to:

[image]

I tried to create a new skin that shows decisecond in right side of second at same scale, but I had no success. Can you give me a clue how should I do that or is it possible at all?

Comment: So when you emailed dries-amine@hotmail.com and asked what you were doing wrong, what response did you get?  When you click on amine5a5's name below the app... you know... the person who created it/shared it through deviantART... there is that contact email right there.  Or, you could just leave a comment right on that page, since the creator seems to respond to what people say.  Wouldn't it be smarter to first attempt to contact the single individual who would most likely know the answer to your question, rather than trying random individuals?

Comment: @BonGart I emailed 'horloger-team (at) hotmail.com', he did not reply.

Comment: Ok.  So, you didn't email the address there at deviantArt, which you gave us a link to, and you didn't post a comment on the Horloger page which has evidence of the author replying, which you also gave us a link to.  Is that what you are saying, when you reply to me by avoiding the questions I actually asked you?  I didn't ask if you emailed a different address.  I asked if you tried to use the contact information on the link you gave to us?  And when did you send this email?

Comment: @BonGart Thanks for your comments, I emailed both addresses. I did not post a comment because it force users to sign up, but ok ok, I will sign up and leave a comment there! Please note that asking a question in this site did not require that users first ask their questions in other sites and waiting for weeks. This site it here to facilitate Q&A.